# Understanding Wikipedia's proof of Spherical law of cosines

Tags: geometry

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines#Second_proof) claims that the angle between $u \times v$ and $u \times w$ is C. However this is the only step I don't understand why it holds.

Context:
Given a unit sphere, a "spherical triangle" on the surface of the sphere is defined by the great circles connecting three points $u$, $v$, and $w$ on the sphere. If the lengths of these three sides are $a$ (from $u$ to $v$), $b$ (from $u$ to $w$), and $c$ (from $v$ to $w$), and the angle of the corner opposite $c$ is $C$.
[image]

Comment: What is it specifically that you don't understand? Why a dihedral angle between two planes is equal to the angle between their (appropriately-selected) normals? Or why the dihedral angle between the planes matches the angle in the spherical triangle? Something else?

Comment: @Blue The first one, why is it the angle between their normals.

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but $u\times v$ would be a vector perpendicular to the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$. Also, when we intersect the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$ with the sphere, we get the "green geodesic" (which is side $a$). Hence you could imagine $u\times v$ as being perpendicular to the green side. A similar story occurs with $u\times w$. With this, I think you can deduce what angle $C$ is. I'll think about this more when I have more time later.

Comment: I think the problem is that I was picking the wrong normals, hence why it seemed false. If the normals are in the right direction, they are both to the, say, right of the planes, it's just like a pi/2 rotation. So obviously the angle between them is the same. Thanks guys.